# How to solve tralling zeros problem in the price?

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to get the item details from shopee.com website. When I try to visit the website using google chrome with the developer tool and start to check the network calls, there is a request that gives a JSON file as response contains all the information of the product which is perfect and good, but the problem is the price, the price have many trailing zeros which not give the correct price as it's written on the website, for example

```
69700000 = ₱697
131700000 = ₱1,317
2990000 = RM29.90
4157000 = 41.5
```

and I can't find anything common to remove those zeros, so if there any help or a function that i can use to give me the right result as on left will be good, the function can be in python, c++ or any programming language in way to solve this tralling zeros and work on any price
here is some of the product urls to check:
[product 1](https://shopee.com.my/Men-Electric-Hair-Clipper-Nose-Trimmer-Beard-Shaver-Trimmer-Cordless-Groomer-Kit-i.52762351.1814616416)
[product 2](https://shopee.ph/Philips-QT4001-Cordless-Beard-Trimmer-shaver-i.45719431.1502196458)
[product 3](https://shopee.ph/Original-Funko-pop-Smallville--Clark-Kent-Vinyl-Action-Figure-Collectible-Model-Toy-i.133530841.2654874393)
[product 4](https://shopee.sg/Svelty-Pakkun-decomposition-yeast-120-Tablets-i.139075719.2136980675)
also I can't find any other request in the network to give the right price as it's shown on the website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For your 4 examples the price is just the value / 100000, not just removing zeros... Not sure why the last one got rounded down, though

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume

```
price_you_have_downloaded_from_internet = "asdfasdf123.2"
```

Then

```
a = price_you_have_downloaded_from_internet
correct_price = ''.join(list(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit() or x == '.', a)))
```